# removeEventListener not working when callback is bound to another object

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I recently noticed that when a callback is passed to the `addEventListener` function that is bound to another object, calling `removeEventListener` later won't work.

Example:

```js
/* 'this' is referencing e.g. a class */
element.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler.bind(this))

/* the event listener won't be removed */
element.removeEventListener('click', this.clickHandler)
```

I found a workaround using the default function `handleEvent` that is being called when you pass an object to `addEventListener`.

```js
/* 'this' is referencing e.g. a class */
element.addEventListener('click', this)

/* the event listener won't be removed */
element.removeEventListener('click', this)

this.handleEvent = function (e) {
  switch(e.type) {
    'click': { 
      this.clickHandler(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote about it [here](https://kostasbariotis.com/removeeventlistener-and-this/).

But, I am curious about why is this happening? Why is that `removeEventListener` doesn't finds the eventHandler to remove it?

Comment: As far as I know, the second parameter must refer to the exactly same function as was used when adding the event (meaning, not only the same _code_, but it must refer to the same function _object_.)

Comment: aha! So `someFunction !== someFunction.bind(someObject)`?? Is this why?

Comment: Ofc, because bind returns always a new function! Great, didnt know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, something that I was missing is that `bind` always returns a new function. This means that I was passing a different function to `removeEventListener` thus it couldn't find it to remove it.